# Is there a concise way to construct a path in JSTL that preserves URL variables?

Tags: jstl

I'm looking for a way, in JSTL, to construct a new URL that contains the URL variables from the current URL.  I would have expected this to be a common need, and for there to be an easy way to do it, but my Googlin' and DuckDuckGoin' has come up empty.

For example, on a page that displays a paginated table of data, you might want to preserve the table's column sorting in URL variables while navigating to the next page of data.

I've been checking out `c:url` and `spring:url` and haven't found anything built-in to preserve URL vars.

Currently, I'm looping through the `param` implicit object and am constructing the URL manually, but it's hideous and I'm hoping and begging for a better way.  Something like the `preserveCurrentParams` attribute below would be grand:

```
<spring:url value="" var="myURLpath" preserveCurrentParams="true">
    <spring:param name="param1" value="${param1Value}" />
    <spring:param name="param2" value="${param2Value}" />
</spring:url>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The request object has the getQueryString method. Can you use that ?

Comment: It looks like the request object is accessible from a JSTL page as `pageContext.request`.  `getQueryString` works, but it can't be included in `spring:url` because `spring:param` isn't smart enough to override existing parameters.  For example, if you have `?pageSize=10` in your current URL, and a `spring:param` for pageSize,  it spits out `?pageSize=10&pageSize=10`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `c:url`:

```
<c:url value="./?myparam=a" var="myurl">
  <c:param name="myparam" value="b"/>
</c:url>
```

This will indeed result in a URL with two `myparam` parameters:

```
./?myparam=b&myparam=a
```

But if you read the parameter:

```
<c:out value="${param.myparam}"/>
```

The result is:

```
b
```